# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 when printing pneumonia images with labels

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to print some pneumonia images with their respective labels using Python and TensorFlow. However, I am getting an error it says there are no images present in bacterial pneumonia class but there should be. I have also attached the screenshot so you can see my file structure

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RWYz.png)

why are there not images in Bacterial label

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


train_dir = '/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/train'
def load_images(data_dir):
    normal_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'NORMAL')
    pneumonia_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'PNEUMONIA')
    normal_images = []
    pneumonia_images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(normal_dir):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(normal_dir, filename))
        img_resized = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))
        img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        normal_images.append(img_rgb)
    for filename in os.listdir(pneumonia_dir):
        if 'virus' in filename:
            label = 0  # Viral pneumonia
        elif 'bacteria' in filename:
            label = 1  # Bacterial pneumonia
        else:
            continue
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(pneumonia_dir, filename))
        img_resized = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))
        img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        pneumonia_images.append((img_rgb, label))
    if not pneumonia_images:
        return np.array(normal_images), np.zeros(len(normal_images))
    else:
        X = np.array(normal_images + [x[0] for x in pneumonia_images])
        y = np.concatenate((np.zeros(len(normal_images)), [x[1] for x in pneumonia_images]))
        return X, y



images, labels = load_images(train_dir)

class_names = ['Normal', 'Viral Pneumonia', 'Bacterial Pneumonia']

def print_images(images, labels, class_names, label_value, num_images=5):
    indices = np.where(labels == label_value)[0]
    if len(indices) == 0:
        print(f"No images found for label '{class_names[label_value]}'")
        return
    if len(indices) < num_images:
        print(f"Only {len(indices)} images found for label '{class_names[label_value]}'")
        num_images = len(indices)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=num_images, figsize=(15, 5))
    for j, ax in enumerate(axes):
        if j >= len(indices):
            break
        idx = indices[j]
        ax.imshow(images[idx])
        ax.set_title(class_names[label_value])
        ax.axis('off')
    plt.show()


print_images(images, labels, class_names, 1)
print_images(images, labels, class_names, 2)
```

I am confused as to why this error is happening and how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I was expecting that my model will print images ofthat contain bacteria images

Comment: Can you please copy the error text into the question, and format it.